# How to fade the colour of a button to another colour?

Tags: objective-c, button, uiview, uicolor

I am trying to change a button from one colour (red) to another colour (yellow) when another button is pressed. I currently have an abrupt change from red to yellow, and would like to add in a quick animation to make the transition a bit smoother. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

UI updates should happen in main tread, but the animation method is in UIView, it is meant to this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:desiredDuration animations:^{
object.property = newValue;
}];
```